# Only show values that are in a ruby hash

Tags: ruby

I have an array of event objects. Each event has a hash called location with keys of name, address, state, city, zipcode. However not all locations have these keys. I only want to display the values of the keys if they are there. Here's my code

```
@events.each do |event|
  if !event.location.empty?
    puts "Location: #{event.location[:name]}, #{event.location[:address]}, #{event.location[:city]}, #{event.location[:state]}, #{event.location[:zipcode]}"
  end 
end
```

This works fine if I have a full address. But if I have just the name of the location it displays like this

```
Location: Central Park, , , ,
```

How can I get rid of those excess commas? Sometimes it could be 2 or 3 trailing commas. I know how to get rid of one but if the number of trailing commas is not set, I'm not sure how to do it. Would prefer to have the location information displayed on one line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
@events.each do |event|
  values = event.location.values_at(:name, :address, :city, :state, :zipcode).compact
  puts "Location: #{values.join(', ')}" unless values.empty?
end
```

---

Or you might want to add a method to your `Event` class.

```
def stringified_location
  values = location.values_at(:name, :address, :city, :state, :zipcode).compact
  values.join(', ') unless values.empty?
end
```

And call it like this:

```
@events.each do |event|
  stringified_location = event.stringified_location
  puts "Location: #{stringified_location}") if stringified_location
end
```

Comment: ... and make that the responsibility of the `event` class too, I should think.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the hash values with `.values` and then combine them into a string with the appropriate delimiter using `.join(", ")`:

```
@events.each do |event|
  if !event.location.empty?
    puts "Location: #{event.location.values.join(", ")}"
  end 
end
```

Comment: Chances are that the values are not in the desired order.

Comment: @Stefan you're absolutely right, and I was working on improving my answer for that reason when spickermann beat me to it. Upvoting him!

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an array with the values and then join them:

```
@events.each do |event|
  if !event.location.empty?
    puts "Location: #{[event.location[:name], event.location[:address], event.location[:city]}, event.location[:state], event.location[:zipcode]].compact.join(', ')}"
  end 
end
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about compact, thought, there should be a more elegant solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is just to put the value in an array and then join them.

```
@events.each do |event|
  if !event.location.empty?
    location = [event.location[:name], event.location[:address], event.location[:city], event.location[:state], event.location[:zipcode]]
    location -= [nil] #remove empty elements
    puts "Location: #{location.join(', ')}"
  end 
end
```